# With Prisma, how to perform a distinct over a specific field of a json column

Tags: prisma

With Prisma, how can I perform a `distinct` over a specific field of a column of type `json`?
For instance, the json column is named `data` and I have to make a distinct on a field named `code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prisma does not directly support distinct operations on JSON fields yet.

However, you can still achieve what you want using raw SQL queries through  `prisma.$queryRaw` or `prisma.$executeRaw` methods ([Reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access))

It could look something like this:

```js
const result = await prisma.$queryRaw`
    SELECT DISTINCT data->>'code' as code
    FROM YourTableName;
`;
```